# Auto text add in textfield in the end

Tags: php

What is best code, for auto add text in the end textfield. I have a code already but it removes the $ sign when i add anything in it.
This is previous code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#price").on("keyUp",function(index,there){
    $(there).val(
      $(there).val().replace("$","") + "$"
    );
  });
});
```

in HTML

```
<input id="input_B" class="rate" value="$" type="text" disabled>
```

Comment: <input id="input_B" class="rate" value="$" type="text" disabled>

Comment: Where is price div (#price)? Share your whole code.

Answer (score 1):

Do check below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#price" ).keyup(function() {
    $("#input_B").val("$ "+ $("#price").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input_B" class="rate" value="$" type="text" disabled>
<input id="price" type="text" placeholder="Type Here" />
```